# Deny unauthorized users?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

```
<location path="ArchiveNews.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>


            <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

I want to deny un-authenticated users to the ArchiveNews.aspx. For some reason this code doesn't want to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Doesn't want to work?  What do you mean by that?  Does it just allow all users?

Comment: Your code is intelligent, if it chooses when to work? Explain more, specify exactly the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this `web.config` exist in the same directory as your `ArchiveNews.aspx` file?  It needs to be in the same directory for your config snippet to control access to that file.

Comment: yea I am inside the "News Foler" which contains "ArhiveNews.aspx" and two other files, also contains this web.config file

Comment: @shenn can you post your whole `web.config` file, as well as your root `web.config` file?

Answer (score -1):

Just disable anonymous access in the gui iis manager for this site/application.

Comment: That isn't the solution to the problem.  UI security is thin.